# java: if.else strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, if-statement

i've a problem with a couple of if-else conditions, here's the code:

```
    if((hour<=16 && min<30)||(hour>=21 && min>0))
    { //copy of if#3
        Log.d("baja", "copy");
        message="something2";
    }

    if ((day>=1 && month>=4) && (day<=30 && month<=9)) 
    { //if#1

        if((hour<=16 && min<30)||(hour>=23 && min>0))
        { //if#2
            message="something";
        }
    }//end of if#1
    else
        { //else for if#1
        Log.d("baja", "before if#3 ");
        if((hour<=16 && min<30)||(hour>=21 && min>0)){ //if#3
            Log.d("baja", "if#3");
            message="something2";
        }
    }
```

the problem is that if the flow enters the else if#3 doesn't work, but the copy i've put outside if#1 works perfectly....what is the problem?

i can't post the exact log now, but i can see "copy" and "before if#3"

Comment: Lets see your debug output as well please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do (If I understand your question correctly). The reason for this is that the else block is attached to the high level if block, rather than it's internal logic. If the if#1 returns false, nothing will happen, if it is true it will test if#2 -> if this is false, it will execute the else statement. If this is not your question, please supply the stack trace as rattmuff requested

```
if ((day>=1 && month>=4) && (day<=30 && month<=9))
{
    if((hour<=16 && min<30)||(hour>=23 && min>0))
    {
    message="something";
    }//if#2
    else
    {
     Log.d("baja", "before if#3 ");
    }//else
}//if#1
else if((hour<=16 && min<30)||(hour>=21 && min>0))
{
    Log.d("baja", "if#3");
    message="something2";
}//if#3
```

Comment: See revised. You are best using an else if